# Need a seconda pair of eyes on Django URL dispatcher

Tags: django, url, dispatcher

Wondering if I could get some help with a second pair of eyes.  Started working Django about two months ago learning in my spare time.  Long story short: My index and post view work fine.  I recently created a contact html\template and view which looks like it goes right back to my index page?  Here is my project urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .settings import MEDIA_ROOT


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^contact/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Here is my app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
                       url(r'^(?P<post_name>\w+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
                       url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

If I change my contact view to come up as my default the view it comes up fine.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
                       url(r'^(?P<post_name>\w+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
                       url(r'^$', views.contact, name='contact'),
                       #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

As soon as switch it back to the original state when I click on the contact link on my page it goes right to my index page.  I have to be doing something wrong with the URL dispatcher part but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contact urlpattern is not matching the URL "/contact", it is matching "/blog/contact" and "/contact/contact". Since you've included the blogs urlpatterns under both those prefixes, the thing that matches "/contact" is the URL without anything after the prefix, ie the index.

You probably don't want to put the contact pattern into the included file at all: just match it directly in the base project file.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  If I go to contact/contact my view comes up.  Could you post a sample of what you talking about so I can better understand and indicate if I'm doing the changes to the project urls.py file or the app urls.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Please mind the order of the urls in your app's urls.py. Try to put your `views.contact` view before your `views.post` view. Keep in mind: Django chooses the first matching regular expression, which is your `views.post` view.

I ran into a similar problem and described the solution [here](http://derpington.de/pay-attention-to-the-order-of-your-urls-in-urlspy/).

Comment: Still going to my views.index.  This is frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Here your contact view has the url /contact/contact/ and index view has the url /contact/

So you have rewrite the project urls as

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .settings import MEDIA_ROOT


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
       {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you guys very much! Just so I know for the future is this a best practice approach that I'm dong or am I completely screwing this up?

Comment: Just because I'm new I should still be able to mark your answers as useful! Just wanted to say thanks again!